# $A \subset \mathbb{R} $ is measurable, prove that $-A=\{x : -x \in A\}$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

$A \subset \mathbb{R} $ is measurable, prove that $-A=\{x : -x \in A\}$ is measurable.

It is more than obvious that $-A$ is measurable, but I am sure that I am not supposed to say :"$-A$ is just $A$ displaced on the real line". My Question is : if I show that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an open set $O$ containing $-A$ such that $m(O \setminus -A) < \epsilon$, does this imply that $-A$ is measurable ?

Comment: How have you defined "measurable"?

Comment: @T.Bongers A is measurable if for any set B in $\mathbb{R}$, we have that $$m^*(B)=m^*(B \cap A)+m^*(B \cap A^c)$$

Comment: I've never studied measure theory, but have you considered $-B$? That seems likely to be rather direct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set $A\subset\mathbb R$ is measurable if and only if $\chi_A$ is a measurable function. But is $f(x)$ is measurable, so is $h(x)=f(-x)$, as $h=f\circ\varphi$, where $\varphi$ is a continuous function. Note that $\chi_{A}(-x)=\chi_{-A}(x)$, and thus $-A$ is also a measurable set.

Answer (score 2):

I reckon you are thinking just of the sigma-algebra of the Borelsets of
$\mathbb{R}$. For that look at the other answers. More general:

$\mathcal{A}:=\left\{ \emptyset,\left(-\infty,0\right],\left(0,\infty\right),\mathbb{R}\right\} $
is also a sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.

Here $A:=\left(-\infty,0\right]$
is measurable (i.e. is an element of $\mathcal{A}$) but $-A=\left[0,\infty\right)$
is **not**.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, consider the family of measurable sets $A$ such that $-A$ is measurable. This is a sigma-algebra which contains every interval hence it contains the sigma-algebra generated by the family of intervals, which is...

Answer (score 0):

Let $A\subseteq \Bbb R$ be measurable. By your definition (whatever $m^*$ means), for any $B\subseteq \Bbb R$
$$m^*(-B)=m^*(-B\cap A)+m^*(-B\cap A^c).$$
I'm betting that $m^*(-X)$ will always equal $m^*(X)$ in some trivial way. But then
\begin{align*}
m^*(B)=m^*(-B)&=m^*(-B\cap A)+m^*(-B\cap A^c) \\
&=m^*(B\cap -A)+m^*(B\cap (-A)^c)
\end{align*}

Comment: Proof of $m^*(A)=m^*(-A)$.  
 Assuming that $m^*$ is the outer measure defined as
$$
m^*(A)=\inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |I_i|: \ I_i\text{'s} \text{ open intervals },\ A\subset \bigcup_i^\infty I_i\right\}
$$

 then for any $x\in A\ \exists\ I_i$ for some $i\geq1$ s.t. $x\in I_i\Rightarrow\ -x\in -I_i\Rightarrow -A\subset\bigcup_i^\infty -I_i$.  
Given $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |-I_i|=\sum_{i=1}^\infty |I_i|$, $m^*(-A)\leq m^*(A)$.  
Apply the same argument to $m^*(-A)$ to show the opposite inequality.  
$$
.
$$
But I do not know if $m^*((-B)\cap A)=m^*(B\cap (-A))$ and $m^*(-(A^c))=m^*((-A)^c)$.

Comment: @Ton Thank you very much !

Comment: @dfeuer I do not exactly see why $m^*((−B)∩A)=m^*(B∩(−A))$